# I have an array declared in a recursive function. How do I sort it?

Tags: c, recursion, directory

I have an array declared inside a recursive function. Is it possible to sort it before outputting? The size I get from another recursive function.

```
void listFilesRecursively(char *basePath, int size) {
    char path[1000];
    struct dirent *dp;
    struct file files[size];
    struct stat buf;
    DIR *dir = opendir(basePath);
    int counter = 0;
    if (!dir) return;
    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") != 0) {
            strcpy(path, basePath);
            strcat(path, "/");
            strcat(path, dp->d_name);
            files[counter].name = path;
            stat(path, &buf);
            files[counter].file_info.st_size = buf.st_size;
            printf("%s%s%ld%s\n", files[counter].name, " - ",
                   files[counter].file_info.st_size, "bytes");
            counter++;

            listFilesRecursively(path, size);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C++

Comment: It’s using VLAs so it can’t be C++ (unless it’s relying on non-standard extensions) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning : `files[counter].name=path` saves a local variable address, and at each loop you modify it, so all the names will be the same, you need to save a duplicate of it (*strdup*)

For each call of *listFilesRecursively* you use more than 1000 bytes in the stack, better to not use that string in the stack and directly works with a path allocated in the heap

I do not see the interest to have *files* and *counters* as local variable, you loose them going out

A proposal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NFILES 100;

typedef struct file  {
  char * name;
  struct stat file_info;
} file;

void listFilesRecursively(char *basePath, file ** files, int * size, int * index) 
{
  DIR *dir = opendir(basePath);

  if (!dir) 
    return;

  struct dirent *dp;
  struct stat buf;

  while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
  {
    if ((strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") != 0))
    {
        size_t sz = strlen(basePath);

        char * pathname = malloc(sz + strlen(dp->d_name) + 2);

        if (pathname == NULL) {
          /* out of memory */
          closedir(dir);
          return;
        }

        strcpy(pathname, basePath);
        pathname[sz] = '/';
        strcpy(pathname + sz + 1, dp->d_name);

        stat(pathname, &buf);

        if (S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)) {
          /* suppose dirs not memorized */
          listFilesRecursively(pathname, files, size, index);
          free(pathname);
        }
        else if (S_ISREG(buf.st_mode)) {
          /* a file, memorize it */
          if (++*index == *size) {
            *size += NFILES;
            *files = realloc(*files, (*size) * sizeof(file));
          }

          (*files)[*index].file_info = buf;
          (*files)[*index].name = pathname;
        }
        else
          /* bypassed */
          free(pathname);
    }
  }

  closedir(dir);
}

int compPathname(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return strcmp(((file *) a)->name, ((file *) b)->name);
}

int main()
{
  int size = NFILES;
  int index = -1;
  file * files = malloc(size * sizeof(file));

  listFilesRecursively(".", &files, &size, &index);

  if (index != -1) {
    qsort(files, index + 1, sizeof(file), compPathname);

    /* write and free memory */
    for (int i = 0; i <= index; ++i) {
      printf("%s : %ld\n", files[i].name, (long) files[i].file_info.st_size);
      free(files[i].name);
    }
  }

  free(files);

  return 0;
}
```

I only memorize the pathname and size of the regular files, the directories and dynamic links etc are not saved

I sort on the pathname

I add NFILES each time files is too small, NFILES can be any number > 0

---

Execution under valgrind :

```
==9329== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9329== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9329== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9329== Command: ./a.out
==9329== 
./.X0-lock : 11
./a.out : 12920
./f.c : 2485
./vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-9329-by-pi-on-??? : 36
==9329== 
==9329== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9329==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9329==   total heap usage: 35 allocs, 35 frees, 339,242 bytes allocated
==9329== 
==9329== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9329== 
==9329== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9329== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Comment: I want to save them in an array of structs... my struct is like that`typedef struct file{
char *name;
struct stat file_info;
}file;` but when I'm declaring this array outside the function i get segmentation fault... because i need the data not only to list but manipulate with, like sort, transfer... Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Nick ah ok, I edited my answer, trivial changes. Warning _files_ must be allocated in the heap because it is reallocated if needed

Comment: @Nick I do not use a constant size to save the pathname (e.g. no `char name[256];` for instance)  both to be sure I can save it whatever its length and to not consume memory for nothing memory when it is shorter that the reserved size. It is quite the same for _files_, I do not use a fixed sized vector to manage any number of files and nor an huge one consuming memory for nothing. _NFILES_ is not 1 to not _realloc_ each time a file is reach

Comment: I'm finishing the project already, but I have the last issue... I'm trying to rename() all the found files to another directory, and the destination should be provided with argv[3] (neccessary requirement) but when i try to do it it prints out garbage, like a few files concatinated together, and of course doesn't copy anything. Justname is a modification of my original struct where I keep the file name without the full path.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= index; ++i) {
            char *dest = argv[3];
                    strcat(dest, "/");
                    strcat(dest, files[i].justname);
      printf("%s : %s : %ld\n", files[i].name, dest , (long) files[i].file_info.st_size);
    if(rename(files[i].name, dest)==0) printf("Success!\n"); else printf("Failed!/n");
    }`

Comment: This is the modified relevant part

Comment: @Nick to use remark for that is not easy, I encourage you to open a new question ;-)

Comment: Thank you! I have asked it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278697/how-to-properly-pass-file-path-with-from-the-command-line

Comment: Edited the second Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278697/how-to-properly-pass-file-path-with-from-the-command-line

Comment: @Nick I reintroduced my answer and edited it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278697/how-to-properly-pass-file-path-with-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does not work:

- there is a new array `files` defined at each recursive level.
- the path saved for each entry in the array is the same, a pointer to the local array `path` defined in the function.

Making `files` a global variable is a possibility, but global variables should be avoided. You should instead pass a pointer a structure defined outside the recursive function and reallocate an array inside this structure as you find more entries during the recursive descent. A copy of the path for each file should be allocated with `strdup`. To limit the stack space requirements, the `path` could also be part of this structure and the length of the directory part passed to the recursive function.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>

struct file {
    char *name;
    struct {
        long st_size;
    } file_info;
};

typedef struct dir_state {
    char path[1024];
    struct file *files;
    int files_size;
    int files_count;
} dir_state;

int listFilesRecursively(dir_state *sp) {
    struct dirent *dp;
    struct stat buf;
    int counter = 0;
    int path_len = strlen(sp->path);
    DIR *dir = opendir(sp->path);
    if (!dir)
        return 0;
    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") != 0) {
            snprintf(sp->path + path_len, sizeof(sp->path) - path_len, "/%s", dp->d_name);
            if (sp->files_count == sp->files_size) {
                int new_size = sp->files_size * 3 / 2 + 16;
                struct file *new_p = realloc(sp->files, new_size * sizeof(*new_p));
                if (new_p == NULL)
                    return -1;
                sp->files_size = new_size;
                sp->files = new_p;
            }
            memset(&sp->files[sp->files_count], 0, sizeof(struct file));
            sp->files[sp->files_count].name = strdup(sp->path);
            if (!stat(sp->path, &buf))
                sp->files[sp->files_count].file_info.st_size = buf.st_size;
            printf("%s%s%ld%s\n", sp->files[sp->files_count].name, " - ",
                   sp->files[sp->files_count].file_info.st_size, "bytes");
            sp->files_count++;
            counter++;
            listFilesRecursively(sp);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
    sp->path[path_len] = '\0';
    return counter;
}

int cmp_name(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct file *aa = a;
    const struct file *bb = b;
    return strcmp(aa->name, bb->name);
}

int cmp_size_name(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct file *aa = a;
    const struct file *bb = b;
    if (aa->file_info.st_size < bb->file_info.st_size)
        return -1;
    if (aa->file_info.st_size > bb->file_info.st_size)
        return +1;
    return strcmp(aa->name, bb->name);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    dir_state ds = { "", NULL, 0, 0 };
    int i;

    if (argc < 2) {
        strcpy(ds.path, ".");
        listFilesRecursively(&ds);
    } else {
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            strcpy(ds.path, argv[i]);
            listFilesRecursively(&ds);
        }
    }
    printf("\nFiles sorted by name:\n");
    qsort(ds.files, ds.files_count, sizeof(*ds.files), cmp_name);
    for (i = 0; i < ds.files_count; i++) {
        printf("%10ld  %s\n", ds.files[i].file_info.st_size, ds.files[i].name);
    }
    printf("\nFiles sorted by size and name:\n");
    qsort(ds.files, ds.files_count, sizeof(*ds.files), cmp_size_name);
    for (i = 0; i < ds.files_count; i++) {
        printf("%10ld  %s\n", ds.files[i].file_info.st_size, ds.files[i].name);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ds.files_count; i++) {
        free(ds.files[i].name);
    }
    free(ds.files);
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- the maximum depth is not limited: since this method follows symbolic links, there could be cycles in the directory tree causing the same paths to be traversed multiple times. This will however not cause infinite recursion, thanks to the path length limit enforced by `snprintf`.