# How to properly pass file path with from the command line?

Tags: c, arrays, argv

I've got a project about moving certain files from one directory to another. I have all finished except that the output is kind of strange. I am required to provide the destination path in the argsv array, but when I try to execute my code, it compiles and works but shows the wrong path containing many paths in one! Here is the relevant part, if you need more code I will add! Thank you in advance!

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

int size = NFILES;
int index = -1;
file * files = malloc(size * sizeof(file));

listFilesRecursively(argv[1], &files, &size, &index);

if (index != -1) {
      int N = atoi(argv[2]);

if(N==1) qsort(files, index + 1, sizeof(file), compPathname);
else if(N==2) qsort(files, index + 1, sizeof(file), compPathsize);

for (int i = 0; i <= index; ++i) {
        char *dest = argv[3];
                strcat(dest, "/");
                strcat(dest, files[i].justname);
  printf("%s : %s : %ld\n", files[i].name, dest , (long)   files[i].file_info.st_size);
//  if(rename(files[i].name, dest)==0) printf("Success!\n"); else     printf("Failed!/n");
}
```

So this is the main. The desired output is like this (I have many files):

```
./copyto.c : /home/nik/copyto.c : 676
Success!
./mvfilrd.c : /home/nik/mvfilrd.c : 957
Success!
./sortall.c : /home/nik/sortall.c : 992
Success!
```

and so on... but instead I get

```
./newdir/newfile.txt : /home/nik/Music/newfile.txt : 0
Success!
./newdir/3.exe : /home/nik/Music/newfile.txt/3.exe : 0
Failed!/n./newdir/compil : /home/nik/Music/newfile.txt/3.exe/test :     0
Failed!/n./newdir/2.c : /home/nik/Music/newfile.txt/3.exe/test/exe :         0
```

and then even more garbage

```
Failed!/n./newf.exe : /home/nik/Music/newfile.txt/3.exe/test/exe    /1//Q�/~�dZ /�l�G^ /
                                                                                    ��`(/4�a^d /a.txt/range/1.txt/1.exe/print.exe/filrd.exeC/2.exre/filrd.exe/2.exe/fi.txt/fil.txt/dest.txt/sorcopy.c/filew.exe/.filer.c.swp    /progfilrd.exe/compile/myfile/.m
```

and the first argument seems to have crashed as well...

Comment: What is the input (how is your programm called)? What is the expected output? What is the output you get instead? Where is your [mcve]?

Comment: I input the source and destination paths ans something else. For example, the part where I need the source path works. So basically I provide the source path, get files, do something with them (sort actually) and copy them to another catalog... The copying part seems weird...

Comment: ouch you modify a argv[3] you do not own, do not do that, you can write out of the string, work on a copy. Are you sure _justname_ is only the name ? because in the other question the _pathname_ is saved, not just the name

Comment: Everything works fine if i hard-code the path inside function...

Comment: I have the screenshots of the current and desired outputs but don't know how to add(sorry I'm new here)

Comment: And yes, I have successfully extracted justname and put to another field (I tested that)

Comment: And the task requirement says I enter the source path as argv[1], then argv[2] is an int to choose the sorting (by name and size), an argv[3] is the destination to copy. Everything works except for the last part, though maybe its argv[1] as well that prevents me from getting the good output

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding information in the comments. There is no need for screenshots. The console output is text and should be copy & pasted as text.

Comment: Ok found how, will update

Comment: char *dest = argv[3]; 
  strcat(dest, "/"); `  there is no place in the memory pointed to by `argv[3]`, you are writing out of bounds, overflowing the stuck (pun). You need to allocate the memory for you strings. `char *dest = malloc(strlen(argv[3] + sizeof("/") - 1 + strlen(files[i].justname) + 1)` or similar.

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *dest = argv[3]; 
strcat(dest, "/"); 
strcat(dest, files[i].justname);
```

ouch you modify a string you do not own, do not do that, you probably write out of the string, work on a copy

replace

```
for (int i = 0; i <= index; ++i) {
    char *dest = argv[3];
    strcat(dest, "/");
    strcat(dest, files[i].justname);
    printf("%s : %s : %ld\n", files[i].name, dest , (long)   files[i].file_info.st_size);
    if(rename(files[i].name, dest)==0) 
       printf("Success!\n");
    else
       printf("Failed!/n");
}
```

by

```
for (int i = 0; i <= index; ++i) {
    size_t sz = strlen(argv[3]);
    char *dest = malloc(sz + strlen(files[i].justname) + 2);

    strcpy(dest, argv[3]);
    dest[sz] = '/';
    strcpy(dest + sz + 1, files[i].justname);

    printf("%s : %s : %ld\n", files[i].name, dest , (long)   files[i].file_info.st_size);
    if(rename(files[i].name, dest)==0)
      printf("Success!\n");
    else
      printf("Failed!/n");

    free(dest);
}
```

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: @Nick after update it's the same code with the same flaw. It didn't make any difference. `char *dest = argv[3];
                strcat(dest, "/");
                strcat(dest, files[i].justname);` is still in the code you presented.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
    char *dest = argv[3]
```

makes `dest` point to the same string that `argv[3]` does.  That is, you have copied the pointer, not the data to which it points.  When you subsequently modify that data through `dest`, you are modifying the argument itself.  This is allowed, but poor form.

The bigger problem is what you actually do with it.  This:

```
  strcat(dest, "/"); 
  strcat(dest, files[i].justname);
```

attempts to append data to the end of the argument string, but it is unsafe to assume (and it is probably incorrect in practice) that there is any free space in the pointed-to array in which to store the extra characters.  If indeed there is not enough space then you produce undefined behavior.

Based on the code you did show and the behavior you describe, I speculate that what you *did not* show might include a similar assignment of another argument pointer to `files[i].justname`.  Such an assignment is not inherently wrong, but it could easily make the manifestation of the UB more confusing than it already was.

In any case, if you want to form concatenations of the program arguments, then you need to reserve separate space for the result.  You can do that with a large-enough automatic array, or with sufficiently large dynamically-allocated space.  The latter might look like this:

```
    size_t path_chars = strlen(argv[3]) + strlen(files[i].justname) + 2;
    char *path = malloc(path_chars);

    if (path) {
        sprintf(path, "%s/%s", argv[3], files[i].justname);
    } // else handle memory allocation failure
```

You can use `strcpy()` and `strcat()` instead if you prefer, but in this particular case I think `sprintf()` is clearer and cleaner.